# Do MySQL transactions lock rows within InnoDB that are being updated and/or selected

Tags: php, mysql, sql, transactions

Using InnoDB, do MySQL transactions lock newly created rows when `BEGIN` is called, and then unlock them when commit is called?
for example:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO employee (ssn,name,phone) 
values ('123-45-6789','Matt','1-800-555-1212')";
mysql_query("BEGIN");
$result = mysql_query($query);
mysql_query("COMMIT);
```

Does the `INSERT` statement lock that row until `COMMIT` is called, or is it rolled back to prevent other concurrent connections from modifying it?
If not, can you only lock a row within a transactions which blocks reads and any modifications by calling select FOR UPDATE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until the transaction is committed, the newly created record is invisible to other connections. Other connections cannot modify it, so there is no need to lock it.

Comment: So regardless of whether its an insert,update or select statement and is called within a transaction it adheres to acid serialization therefore is locked(cannot be read or written by other transactions?)

Comment: Yes, by default. Except you configure the --transaction-isolation option to something else. For more information read this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html

Comment: when you say the "newly create record is created it is invisible to other connections so there is no need to lock it" what if the record isnt new, and instead of insert, 'update' is called? the table to update would need to be locked by a select FOR UPDATE within the transaction true?  see:http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/10897_3382171_2/Transactions-in-MySQL.htm

Comment: Hi tommo, my answer about what happen when an update is carried out in a transaction was not correct. Let me correct it. When you carried out an update on a record in a transaction, that record will be automatically locked until the transaction is committed. `SELECT...FOR UPDATE` puts a lock on the selected records, and if any of the selected record still has a lock on it, the select will wait until the lock is released before returning the result.

Comment: That link is useful for me too. Thanks for that!